# How to recognize a parabola from an algebraic expression?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

**Context**.  I worked on an intermediate-value-theorem problem that asked whether $f(x) = x^{10} - 10x^2 + 5$ had a root in $(0, 2)$.  I solved the problem by computing $f(0)$ and $f(2)$, both of which are positive, making me try again.  However, I (incorrectly) thought to myself --- that's a parabola because of the even degree, so let's take a point $x=a$ inside the interval.  (Being a parabola, it has to go further down, so I can find whether it gets below the $x$-axis.)  Then I tried $f(1)$, which is negative.  So, yes, I concluded --- there must be a root by the intermediate value theorem.  "Problem solved".  But I graphed the function to discover that it's **not** a parabola.

The **question** is --- how could I recognize a parabola from the algebraic expression of a function?

Comment: a parabola has quadratic terms, but not $10^{th}$ power terms

Comment: it's not a parabola. It's a W

Comment: I learned that while I've been saying "parabola", what I really meant to say was a "curve with a U-like shape".  Because the function I worked with is W-like shape, it could have more than two real roots... So my question should've been a different one.  It should have been --- how I can tell whether the curve is a U-shaped one?  (Sometimes I can't even ask the right question.)

Comment: As others have noted, not a parabola which has degree 2. But it does have even degree (10) though not an even function.  Having even degree means its behavior will be the same towards both $\pm\infty$, and without further investigation that means a "U" or "W" shape or similar (or upside down if the leading coefficient is negative). Suggestion is to always analyze carefully and graph - there was no Desmos when some of us learned this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parabolas have a leading term with a "squared" exponent. A polynomial in descending order whose leading coefficient has any exponent other than $2$ is not quadratic.

Answer (score 8):

A parabola where $y$ is a function of $x$ is $y = a x^2 + b x + c$ where $a, b, c$ are constants and $a \ne 0$.  A more general parabola is $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d x + e y + f = 0$ where $b^2 - 4 a c = 0$.